# Is there a way to check if the current export is imported in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

In commonjs (node) I can do this:

```
module.exports = {...}
if (module.parent) {...}
```

Is there something similar in typescript? I'm writing a web app and it would allow me to not bind a port during tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is not responsible for providing such functionality. It is entirely the responsibility of your module loader (e.g. Node's built-in module loading code, SystemJS, RequireJS) or bundler (e.g. Webpack, Browserify) to provide such functionality. If you compile your TypeScript code and run it in Node, then yes, `module.parent` will be there though it is not declared in the TypeScript declarations by default. If you install the NPM package `@types/node`, you'll get a declaration for it though. (`npm install @types/node`) Or you can declare it yourself if you prefer.